# Why i get `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` on unit testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, unit-testing, jquery-ui

I use `react-testing-library` to test some of my components that they use jquery.
The application runs fine, but when i go to test them, i get that `jQuery` is not defined.
That is called inside `node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js` where is calls `factory(jQuery)`

---

**Yarn test gives: **.

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

```
  2 | import { video } from '../player';
  3 |
> 4 | import 'jqueryui';
    | ^
  5 | require('./jquery-ui-touch-punch');
  6 |
  7 | export default function() {
```

---

The error happening on a js file, that is used by the component:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDifX.png // i dont know why, it does not display the image.

Where does jquery need to be imported, so not to get that error ?

---

The jquery modules that i use in `package.json` are:

````
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.10",
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",```
````

Answer (score 1):

import jquery first since it should be in scope or if it is available, tell the compiler that it's global like `/*  global $, jQuery, jquery */

Comment: if you check the image link, i import jquery on the 1st line like so: `import * as $ from 'jquery';`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDifX.png

Comment: I don't see the images, I see the code shown right into the post